# How do I change the visibility of a hyperlink when the mouse moves over it?

Tags: html, css, hover, visibility, hyperlink

How can I make a link visible only when one hovers over the link?

Comment: I've just got to ask - why? And how would one know what to hover over if the link is invisible?

Comment: At least think of the user when doing this. They should know what is and what isn't a link. Color it differently at least if you don't want the underline to show.

Comment: The only reason I can imagine for actually hiding the link is if it were an easter egg in a game or something.

Comment: @homestead: did any of the answers solve your problem?  If so, you should accept it.  If not, please leave some feedback saying why this doesn't help.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
a:link, a:visited {
    visibility: hidden;
}
a:link:hover, a:visited:hover {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

---

**Edit**    After piquadrat pointed out that Firefox doesn’t hover invisible elements, try this instead:

```
a:link span, a:visited span {
    visibility: hidden;
}
a:link:hover span, a:visited:hover span {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

And the corresponding HTML:

```
Lorem <a href="foo"><span>foo</span></a> ipsum dolor sit amet …
```

Comment: Could I set the hover option dynamically via jquery?

Comment: @homestead, The `:hover` pseudoselector can't be 'set' in Javascript as far as I know (in a standard way, anyway).  You could make a class `hover` and use that.

Comment: @homestead: Sure: `$("head")[0].append('<style type="text/css"> … </style>')`

Comment: could I possibly change the class of the element on the fly that would make it visible upon hover? (doing it on certain elements under certain conditions, that's why I need to do it dynamically)

Comment: @homestead: Well than add a class selector to the selector of the CSS rules.

Comment: gumbo, sorry I don't follow you... add a class selector to the selector?

Comment: @homestead: Use `a.class:link, a.class:visited` instead and add your elements to that class.

Answer (score 2):

Did you mean you'd like the link to appear like normal text?

If so:

```
a { text-decoration: none; color: inherit; }
a:hover, a:active { text-decoration: underline; color: #00F; }
```

Answer (score 2):

The answers that used `visibility` CSS rule don't work for me, at least not in FF.  The link is not visible, so when you move the mouse over it FF thinks you are hovering over whatever is *behind* the link.

This works for me though (even in IE6!):

```
a {
  zoom: 1; filter: alpha(opacity = 0); /* For IE */
  opacity: 0.0;
}
a:hover {
  zoom: 1; filter: alpha(opacity = 100); /* For IE */
  opacity: 1.0;
}
```

Comment: After reading `visibility` didn't work I immediately thought of using `opacity` like in your answer.  +1.  Note: the `zoom` and `filter` are needed only for IE6 (and below?) and not for IE7 or IE8 (as far as I know).

Comment: @strager: actually zoom/filter is still needed on IE8.  (I just tested it to make sure)